# Python and twitch api

Tags: python, api, twitch

I'm working on a project for an exam: "social media mining". 
I'm going to study the network of the channels with most follower on Twitch. 
nodes will be the tops channels and the link will be with them and who they follow. (not who follow those channels)

The problem is that I just can't manage to have the list. I'm messing up with the code. The second request gives problem and the while goes on loop becouse the array "seguiti"  don't fill. In particular on that line seguiti.append(k['channel']['display_name']).

I'm a real noob with python so maybe is a silly error but I invoke your help becouse I really can't get out of this problem!
Thank you very much.

```
off=0
n=0
top_channel = ['Ninja'] #for tests
seguiti = []
for user in top_channel:
    print(user)   
    follows_url = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/{}/follows/channels?client_id={}&offset=0&limit=100'.format(user,client_id))
    follows_json= json.loads(follows_url.text)


    for j in follows_json['follows']:
            seguiti.append(j['channel']['display_name'])

    print(len(seguiti))
    print('total:')
    print(follows_json['_total'])


    while len(seguiti)< follows_json['_total']:

        off=off+100
        follows_url2 = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/{}/follows/channels?client_id={}&offset={}&limit=100'.format(user,client_id, off))
        follows_json2= json.loads(follows_url2.text)

        #pp.pprint(follows_json2['follows'])

        for k in follows_json2['follows']:
                seguiti.append(k['channel']['display_name'])  #apparently it doesn't work
                print(len(seguiti))
                print(k['channel']['display_name'])

                n=n+1
        print(len(seguiti))




print(follows_json['_total'])
print(len(seguiti))
print(seguiti)
```

EDIT: the data structure I want to obtain at the and is:
[dataStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWqxu.png)

Comment: What are you trying to reach. Do you want a structure like this? `Ninja -> Someone who follows Ninja -> Someone that follows the Ninja follower` ?

Comment: thank you for answering. I'm gonna construct a network where the nodes will be the channel with most followers ex('Ninja', 'shroud'...and so on) and thw link will be between these channels and who they follows ex [('Ninja', 'faker') , ('Ninja', 'every user Ninja follows')].      Ninja-> someone who Ninja itself follows.

Comment: I cannot quite understand what kind of datastructure you want. Can you draw it maybe? :P That makes thing most of the time understandable

Comment: Yeah but that is the next step, first i need to obtain the list, and then I will find a way to store it properly! I edited the post with an image, maybe is better :)

Comment: Instead of re-implementing a Twitch API client from scratch, I strongly recommend to use an existing package. For example this one: https://github.com/tsifrer/python-twitch-client. These will already have solved the issues you are battling here.

Comment: The `_total` count is not equal to the number in the `follows` array. So thats why your code doesn't work. And you should use the new API instead of the old one. You can find the references over **[here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-users-follows)**